# AWS IAM Requests Time Out

Tags: amazon-web-services

Trying to use AWS to host a website, but I'm going nowhere. I was able to get an instance set up, but practically anything I try to do times out. I am trying to set up IAM Management, but I can't even create a user or a group without it timing out. I've checked my internet connection and it seems fine in every other regard. I've completely disabled Windows firewall. Still no luck. What am I doing wrong here?

[image: Here's a screenshot of the error I encounter on AWS.]

Comment: What is the nature of your Internet connection? What country are you in?

Comment: I connect through a mesh network because I live out in the country. It's not fast at all to say the least, but it should be adequate. I'm just outside of Fort Worth, Texas. 

speedtest.net is showing a ping of 19ms with 15Mbps down and 3Mbps up. I'm having no other issues that I know of. I guess I'll just hurry up and wait to see if Amazon's fix resolves it. Thanks.

Comment: That ought to be more than sufficient. It probably is on Amazon's end, then.

Answer (score 1):

IAM is currently having some issues:

[IAM operational issue - Increased Error Rates & Latencies](https://phd.aws.amazon.com/phd/home?region=ap-southeast-2#/dashboard/open-issues?eventID=arn:aws:health:global::event/IAM/AWS_IAM_OPERATIONAL_ISSUE/AWS_IAM_OPERATIONAL_ISSUE_TFRHV_1600294646&eventTab=details&layout=vertical)

In other words - wait until they resolve it ;)

Comment: I sure hope that's it. Thank you for your answer.